# I am looking for another alternative to "X = X1(abs(N(4,:)-N(5,:))>0.24*abs(N(5,:)))"

Tags: matlab, matrix

**The objective of this question:**

I am looking for a code that does not take into account the column order of the matrices `N` and `M`. So I try to replace  the following line in the code below :

```
X = X1(abs(N(4,:)-N(5,:))>0.24*abs(N(5,:)));
```

The result `X` is dependent on the column order of `N` and `M`

**The problem:**

my goal is to put all values of `M(4,:)` corresponding to `N(1:3,i), i=1,2,3,4,5` in one vector of a cell `X` if `abs(N(4,i)-N(5,i)) > 0.24*abs(N(5,i))`

`N(1:3,:)` is formed by unique column vectors of `M(1:3,:)`

`N(4:5,:)` is used for finding `X`

The entity `A` is added to display `M` otherwise.

```
M = [1007  4044  1007  4044  1007  5002 5002 5002 622 622  1007  1007  1007;
      552   300   552   300   552   431  431  431 124 124   552    11    11; 
     2010  1113  2010  1113  2010  1100 1100 1100  88  88  2010    20    20;
       12    25    15    12    30     2   10   55  32  12     7    12     7];


A = [1007  4044  5002  622  1007
      552   300   431  124    11
     2010  1113  1100   88    20
       12    25     2   32    12
       15    12    10   12     7
       30          55
        7                        ]

N =  [622  1007 1007  4044  5002;
      124    11  552   300   431;
       88    20 2010  1113  1100;
        2     4 -1.1   2.1    -3;
     2.01     1   -1     2    -5];

[~,~,idx] = unique(M(1:3,:)','rows','stable')


%// Accumulate elements from the fourth row of M based on the IDs
X1 = accumarray(idx(:),M(4,:).',[],@(x) {x});   

%// Use mask corresponding to abs(N(4,i)-N(5,i))>0.24*N(5,i) and
%// filter out some of the cells from the output
X = X1(abs(N(4,:)-N(5,:))>0.24*abs(N(5,:)));
```

**For my example:**
if `N` and `M` are ordered properly:

```
X = {[12,7],[2 10 55]}
```

`[12 7]` correspond to `N(1:3,2)`,  `abs(N(4,2)-N(5,2))>0.24*abs(N(5,2))`

`[2 10 55]` correspond to `N(1:3,5)`,  `abs(N(4,5)-N(5,5))>0.24*abs(N(5,5))`

**Possible Solution:** (gives correct result with my real data)

```
for i = 1:size(N,2)
    N(6,i) = i;
end


for h = 1:size(M,2)
    for l = 1:size(N,2)
        if M(1:3,h) == N(1:3,l) 
           M(5,h) = N(6,l);
        end
    end
end

p = 0;  
for i = 1:size(N,2)
    if abs(N(4,i)-N(5,i))>0.24*abs(N(5,i))
       Mint = M(:,ismember(M(5,:).',i.', 'rows').'); 
       p = p+1;
       X{1,p} = Mint(4,:);
    end
end
```

Comment: do you want a solution that creates an N from M and then performs the analysis regardless of M? or do you want a solution that takes the N and M given as it seems you have the solution for the explicit problem that you presented, are you asking for one that can do this from any matrix M regardless of the location of values in M or N?

Comment: @bern : N and M are the initial data of the problem.  And the solution should be applicable to any matrix M regardless of the location of values in M or N.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ismember` is a good solution to your problem. It tells you when elements (or rows) of one matrix occur in a second matrix and will be much faster than your method using loops. This code matches your solution on the larger dataset you posted:

```
isGood = abs(N(4,:)-N(5,:))>0.24*abs(N(5,:));

[junk, inds] = ismember(M(1:3, :)', N(1:3, isGood)', 'rows');

X = cell(1, sum(isGood));
for i = 1:sum(isGood)
    X{i} = M(4, inds==i);
end
```

Answer (score 1):

See if this works for you -

```
%// Inputs
M = [1007  4044  1007  4044  1007  5002 5002 5002 622 622  1007  1007  1007;
      552   300   552   300   552   431  431  431 124 124   552    11    11; 
     2010  1113  2010  1113  2010  1100 1100 1100  88  88  2010    20    20;
       12    25    15    12    30     2   10   55  32  12     7    12     7];

N =  [622  1077 1007  4044  5002;
      124    11  552   300   431;
       88    20 2010  1113  1100;
        2     4 -1.1   2.1    -3;
     2.01     1   -1     2    -5];

[unqrows,~,idx] = unique(M(1:3,:)','rows','stable')
unqcols = unqrows.';

%// Accumulate elements from the fourth row of M based on the IDs
X1 = accumarray(idx(:),M(4,:).',[],@(x) {x});  %//'

%// "Regularize" X1  %//'
[~,sort_idx] = sortrows(unqcols.');  %//'
X1_sorted = X1(sort_idx);

%// Use mask corresponding to abs(N(4,i)-N(5,i))>0.24*N(5,i) and
%// filter out some of the cells from the output
X = X1_sorted(abs(N(4,:)-N(5,:))>0.24*abs(N(5,:)));

%// Sort, keep unique elements and make them row vectors 
%// within each cell of X (if needed)
X = cellfun(@(x) unique(x).',X,'Uni',0);
```

Output -

```
>> celldisp(X)
X{1} =
     7    12
X{2} =
     2    10    55
```

Comment: Always the same problem! I added in my question a solution, associated with your answer to the other question, gives correct results with my real data.

Comment: @bzak Your possible solution doesn't work with the toy example listed in the question, right? The output from it doesn't seem to match with the expected output there.

Comment: @bzak So, how do you know my posted solution doesn't work?

Comment: I have done an error in N (I put 1077 instead of 1007), now my possible solution work. Concerning your solution, I have associated this with the response to the other question, and I found that the result out was wrong. I think the problem is how to find X.

Comment: @bzak So, are you saying your possible solution works now? With both the actual/real input and also with the toy example listed in the question?

Comment: yes Divakar and associated with your answer to the other question, it gives correct results 'out' with my real data.

Comment: the question now is how with N false your solution gives a correct result with the example listed in the question?

Comment: @bzak I haven't got much clues how you are correlating this and the other bounty question.

Comment: I was checking the result of the other bounty question by comparing 'out' and 'N' (if out(:,n)=N(1:3,m) we must have abs(N(4,m)-N(5,m))<=0.24*abs(N(5,m))). But if the calculation of X is false, and since X is calculated from 'N', it will necessarily appear in the results 'out'.

Comment: @bzak I am lost in all that `N` and `X`, can't figure out, which one to stick to. Sorry, really.

Comment: I am very grateful to you for all the effort you have put to help me during these latest days :)

Answer (score 1):

Using logical indexing will speed up your script dramatically. MATLAB is not really doing well with for loop. Try the following code:

```
k = size(N,2);
r = size(M,2);
M(5:7,:) = 0;

for ii = 1:k
    index = sum(M(1:3,:) == repmat(N(1:3,ii),1,r),1)>2;
    M(5,index) = ii;
    M(6,index) = N(4,ii);
    M(7,index) = N(5,ii);
end

filter = abs(M(6,:)-M(7,:))>0.24*abs(M(7,:));

X = {};
for ii = 1:k
    X = [X, M(4,M(5,:) == ii& filter)];
end
```

On my computer, executing your code took 0.017825 seconds. Mine took 0.002780 seconds. I'd say that's quite some improvement. If you want to have a more detailed comparison, use [profile](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/profile.html).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But with my real data I find two different results with your code and my "Possible solution"  !!!

Comment: Do you mind posting some of the data that would lead to different result between your possible solution and mine? I mean supposedly my code is working in the same principle as yours. I just use `repmat` to expand what you need from the `N` as selection criteria and append to M so it can run faster.

Comment: ok. So I ran your code and mine on the dataset. The primary difference is that your code will give yield empty cell but mine won't. If you look at the content within the cell array that actually contains data, my code is generating the same result as yours. If there is indeed a reason for you to want to have empty cells when the selection criteria is not met, it can be coded that way. Is that truly what you want?

Comment: and the reason for this difference is this: you use only the selection criteria `abs(N(4,i)-N(5,i))>0.24*abs(N(5,i))` to add a cell to the cell array, regardless of whether `M(:,ismember(M(5,:).',i.', 'rows').')` will turn any result. I combine these two selection criteria together, so I ended up with no empty cell.

Comment: I eliminated the empty vectors and repetitions for the two cases, and I find different results !!!

Comment: ok. my bad. it's this line `index = sum(M(1:3,:) == repmat(N(1:3,ii),1,r),1)>1;` that causes trouble.  It should be >2 but not >1 if we're looking for equality of  three elements. I've edited the code above. It should give the same results as your solution.